# Can I embed my own website in webview of android application?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm thinking about it from a very long time. Can I embed my own website in webview of android application?? Am I not violating Google Play developer policies?

Any help?

Comment: You just want to call your website through the webView?

Comment: @kai yes.. That's all I want to do.....

Comment: Than it should be no problem. About what you are thinking about?

Answer (score 1):

Nop, you can embed any website you want. You aren't restrict.

Here is an example of how you can load your website with the URL :

```
this.webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.string.webview);

        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

        progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "WebView Example", "Loading...");

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Processing webview url click...");
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Finished loading URL: " +url);
                if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                }
            }

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + description);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage(description);
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        return;
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        webview.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.com");
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't need the code. I already have full working app. But I'm afraid to publish it in the google play because they have this Policy which says ""Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to: Provide a webview of a website not owned or administered by you (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do so.""

Comment: But if it's your website, there is nothing against that. "website not owned", so here, nop.